# Android Facebook SDK - How To Query Facebook Friend Requests

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have the Facebook SDK for Android used in my app. I can't seem to find any examples or documentation on how to use the SDK code to get Friend Requests. I have the permission "read_requests" set. Does anyone know the graphPath parameter that should be used for Friend Request?

example: "me/????????"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`me/friendrequests`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friendrequests

Comment: Awesome! What is the graphPath for Messages? I see Pokes and outbox, but i am looking for the path for new messages a user receives.

Comment: You probably want the `notifications` method listed on the same page.

Comment: I know that the faceook api is not the best or the best documented, but are you sure? I assume that since there are 3 "types" of notification icons on the facebook html page, that there should be 3 ways to query them....Friend Requests, Messages & Notifications

Comment: There is a whole bunch of different endpoints listed on the page. If you look through them you should find what you want. I just glanced at it and `updates` is another potential one.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Abraham. I'll send myself some test messages and see where they end up on the API.

Comment: FYI: The path for Facebook messages (your Facebook inbox) is this "me/inbox".